# How to get jquery validation status with knockout custom binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I try to create view model that has no view information, such as calling jquery validation directly from view model before saving / sending the data to server.

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.password = ko.observable();
    self.save = function (form) {
       // I want to prevent any view information call directly from view model.
       if ($(form).isValid()) {
          // $.ajax({});
       }
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { data_bind = "submit: save" }))
```

Also I don't want to recreate knockout validation manually in the view model, because they have been generated by asp.mvc data annotation as jquery validation attributes.

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMinStringLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Locale), MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { data_bind = "value: Password" })

// Generated html in the browser view source.
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" data-val-required="The Password field is required." data-val-length-min="6" data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val="true" data-bind="value: Password">
```

I have created a simple custom binding that will update the the valid status as follow.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryIsValid = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).closest("form").change(function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var isValid = $(element).valid();
            observable(isValid);
        });
    }
};
```

And then update the html and view model as follow.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { data_bind = "submit: save, jQueryIsValid: isValid" }))

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.password = ko.observable();
    self.isValid = ko.observable();
    self.save = function () {
       if (self.isValid()) {
          // $.ajax({});
       }
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

My point is to enforce mvvm pattern where as viewmodel should ideally have no knowledge about the view (like $(form).dosomething). I just not sure that above solution is the best way to do it. I might miss something about custom binding or existing knockout feature since I'm new to knockout.

Could anybody show the right / best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom binding is unnecessary.  The view-model doesn't need to be aware of the forms validity.  The point being that `save` should only ever be called on a valid form.  Also since you intend to replace the submit behaviour with an AJAX call you will need to ensure that upon clicking a submit button the form is **not** posted back.

You can achieve this as follows...

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        viewModel.save();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's probably the same like my original code, I use submit event binding from knockout data_bind = "submit: save", and you use submit event from jquery.

Comment: Either method to handle `submit` is equally valid.  The point I'm making is that validity is checked outside the scope of your `save` function and you **must** call `e.preventDefault()` otherwise the browser with post the form and you will not observe your asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: I'm implementing the mvvm pattern on the js using knockout, and based on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm_and_view_models, "When using KO, your view models are pure JavaScript objects that hold no knowledge of HTML", and the problem with my original code is I have to have this "if ($(form).isValid())" code to validate before saving. And then I tried to create my own binding handler, but I'm not sure whether there is already such functionality in KO, also it triggers form validation every time form's changed. I expected something like ko.IsValid(), if there is any.

Comment: No there isn't anything like that.  The sample I've given here strictly enforces MVVM.  The submit handler contains knowledge of the `<form>` allowing us to test for `$(this).valid()` and call `e.preventDefault()`.  This means your view-model does not need knowledge of DOM.